# Set headers to GET/POST request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http-headers

We want to send authentication token and signature during GET/POST request. We are not preferring to send security information through body Or parameter. So we decided to send through headers in request.

When we googled we got to know that we can do this using ajax post request. But we want to move to next pages with headers.

How we can implement this?

**Edited:**

We had plan to store these information on cookies. But in iPhone if cookies is disabled will change behaviour of our website. So to overcome we are planning to send through headers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `X-AUTHENTICATION-TOKEN` in ajax request something as below which I am using for a real time REST API call via ajax requests.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-AUTHENTICATION-TOKEN', 'token string');
    },
```

The server side must set the header something as

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN');
```

And to retrieve the data on server side you may have

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN'])) {
    $request_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN'];
} else {
    if (function_exists('getallheaders')) {
        foreach (getallheaders() as $header_name => $header_value) {
            if ($header_name == 'X_AUTHENTICATION_TOKEN') {
                $request_header = $header_value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So here `$request_header` will be the token and you can use this in the server side script for validation.

Comment: But through Ajax call I can't move to next new html page. I want to move to next page with headers.

Comment: I did not get is't it you want to send request using ajax with token enclosed ? What do you mean by move new html page ? In EMBER.JS we do this kind of operation where token is stored on cookie and token is sent with different server requests when we move across different server requests via html pages and cookie is deleted once the browser is closed.

Comment: Say you have two html pages 'submit form' and 'display details'. If you click on submit button of html page 'submit form' data should save on server and new html page  'display details' will be displayed.

Comment: yes this is exactly we do , we grab the token on login store on cookie and for each server request send the token value as above.

Comment: Hmm that would be difficult to handle if the cookie is disabled, since all modern web apps needs cookie to be enabled. You may check oauth framework http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html